# Where to Initialize MEF DirectoryCatalog in WCF App?

Tags: wcf, mef

So, in a WCF application, is there a magic Application_Start or something like that where I can compose the MEF container from an assembly directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the Constructor of your service, it will be called if your service is activated. Note that if you are hosting in IIS, this is not when the application pool starts, but rather when the first call is submitted to the service.

Comment: What if I need to import a class that is the one I use to resolve the extensions directory path before composing?

Comment: I dont think I understand your comment completely, do you want to import the class to resolve the path using MEF?

Comment: Is there a way to make the container compose itself from a directory using a value in the app.config settings? Just wondering.

Comment: Sure, use a DirectoryCatalog which accepts a string pointing to the path where your assemblies are located, add it to a CompositionContainer and get your class

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the lifetime of your service. A singleton service is likely fine, as the `DirectoryCatalog` will only need to be created once. With a non-singleton service, the `DirectoryCatalog` would be created each time the service is instantiated, which can be a bit slow (as a `DirectoryCatalog` scans the folder to attempt to load the assemblies). `CompositionContainer` instances are quite cheap to spin up.  What I tend to do, is provide an interface abstraction:

```
public interface ICompositionContainerFactory
{
  CompositionContainer CreateCompositionContainer();
}
```

Which I would wire up:

```
public static class CompositionContainerBuilder
{
  private static readonly CompositionContainer _container;

  static CompositionContainerBuilder()
  {
    var factory = CreateCompositionContainerFactory();
    _container = factory.CreateCompositionContainer();
  }

  public static CompositionContainer Container { get { return _container; } }

  private static ICompositionContainerFactory CreateCompositionContainerFactory()
  {
    Type factoryType = // Get from somewhere - configuration perhaps?
    return (ICompositionContainerFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType);
  }
}
```

If you are happy that you only need to create a container once, you can get away with this method. You'd build an instance of `ICompositionContainerFactory` which you then configure. The container is built once (and only once) through the static constructor. You can then use `CompositionContainerBuilder.Container` to grab the container.  Next, just wire up your MEF container through an `IInstanceProvider` and attach it to the service as an `IServiceBehavior`.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by creating my own InstanceProvider (implementing IInstanceProvider). I create an endpoint behavior extension that allowed me to configure the assemblies i want for the composition.
I used assembly catalogs but the principal is the same.

In the end, the XML configuration looks this:

```
 <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
      <enableWebScript/>
  <endpointComposed>
    <assemblies>
        <add name="sampleApplication" value="SampleApplication"/>
    </assemblies>
      </endpointComposed>
    </behavior>                
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

Very straightforward and easy to reuse across projects. No need to put composition logic in your service code which is what i like about it.

I have a full article about this on: https://yoavniran.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/unit-testing-wcf-and-mef-part-2/ and the code sample on: https://bitbucket.org/yoavniran/wcf-mef-and-testing-sample-code/src